# htaccess redirection to index.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

To respect SEO directives, I want to redirect all traffing coming from:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
http://mywebsite.com
www.mywebsite.com
mywebsite.com
```

to

```
http://wvw.mywebsite.com/index.html
```

At the moment I use this code, but it doesn't work properly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L].
```

All works, but still doesn't redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/index.html` in case of `www.mywebsite.com`.

Comment: If you want to redirect everything to `index.html`, why do you pass the URL-path `^(.*)$` to the substitution URL with back reference `$1`? That's not clear, please update your question with a detailed explanation.

Comment: I have updated my code...can you tell me where is the mistake? Unfortunately I'm not good at all with htaccess expressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect VUSAN, thank you very much, all is good but if I digit www.mywebsite.com it doesn't redirect to www.mywebsite.com/index.html....how can I solve this problem too?

Comment: Now put this code on your last   `RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]`

Comment: I have updated my code...can you tell me where is the mistake? Unfortunately I'm not good at all with htaccess expressions...